# Were Hasselblad cameras used in space after the Apollo mission?

Tags: iss, apollo-program, photography, mir

Analog Hasselblad cameras with photochemical film were used extensively during the Apollo mission to the Moon.

Were they used later for Spacelab, Space Shuttle and Mir or ISS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Partial answer:

Hasselblad 500 EL/M cameras were used early in the Shuttle program, before the advent of digital photography.

The training manual is available [here](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/48157108/the-astronauts-photography-manual-pdf-hasselblad), it has this beautiful cover

[image]

I do not know when the transition to digital photography was completed.

This picture shows STS-59 (1994) crewmember Sid Guiterrez holding a Hasselblad in the shuttle cockpit in space. That may be another floating to his right.

[image]

Image source: [https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/sts059-19-004/sts059-19-004~orig.jpg](https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/sts059-19-004/sts059-19-004%7Eorig.jpg)

This picture shows STS-46 (1992) crewmember Marsha Ivins with two Hasselblads.

[image]

Image source: [https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/sts046-03-032/sts046-03-032~orig.jpg](https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/sts046-03-032/sts046-03-032%7Eorig.jpg)

Searching for "hasselblad" in images.nasa.gov turns up a lot more interesting pictures.

Comment: Ironically enough, that cover shows an image that no astronaut could ever take as a photo... right?

Comment: @AakashM What about an astronaut in the ISS watching a Shuttle before docking or after undocking?

Comment: @Uwe ah forgot about that!

Comment: @Uwe cargo bay doors would be open in those circumstances tho, right?

Comment: I asked https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129043/hasselblad-cameras-used-in-space-shuttle-analog-or-digital/129045#129045 and got the answer "Hasselblad did not make digital backs or digital cameras until much later."

Comment: This image https://images.nasa.gov/details-s98e5161 is commented "The scene was taken with a digital still camera. " So in the mission STS98-E-5161 (11 February 2001) digital cameras were used.

Comment: @Uwe way before that, NASA manufactured a digital back that interfaced with Nikon F4, making it one of the first digital backs/cameras to go into space, back in 1991. Starting development in 1987 it went into space aboard Shuttle Discovery during STS-48.

Comment: @Uwe Hasselblad did not make their own backs until around 2006-7, but before then certain Hasselblad bodies accepted digital backs from other manufacturers like Ixpress, Imacon, Kodak, Phase One, Leaf, and were often sold bundled as such. Hasselblad locked out 3rd party backs in 2007 to support their own back. Digital backs were available from the early 1990s, the early versions requiring tethering to computers. I still run a back from 2004.

Comment: shuttle Nikon w/ Kodak back https://www.si.edu/object/camera-digital-nikon-shuttle%3Anasm_A20080108000

Answer (score 4):

A Hasselblad image of the Mir.

[image]

> Docking target on Mir space station as seen from Shuttle Discovery
> NASA ID: sts063-711-069 STS063-711-069 (3-11 Feb. 1995) --- This
> close-up scene of Russian Mir Space Station's docking target was
> exposed by one of the STS-63 crew members using a handheld Hasselblad
> camera during close proximity operations between the space shuttle
> Discovery and Russia's Mir Space Station.
> Date Created: 1995-02-06

[Source](https://images.nasa.gov/details-sts063-711-069)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they were used on the space shuttle inside the cabin. So this [iconic image](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/astronaut-bruce-mccandless-on-first-ever-untethered-spacewalk-0) of Bruce McCandless II was taken with a Hasselblad Camera from inside the cabin of the Orbiter.
[image: Bruce McCandless II free floating]

I could not find any references of them being used outside the cabin (the one you see mounted to the MMU in the image is (almost certainly) a Nikon F3 wrapped in thermal blankets.

Hasselblads were used for quite some time. [This Image](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/1860/jungfrau-and-interlaken-switzerland) was taken in 2000 on STS-106
[image: Jngfrau and Interlaken]

So Hasselblads were for sure used after Apollo well into the shuttle area.

Answer (score 1):

The STS-61 Post Flight Presentation mentions that a Hasselblad was used outside the cabin during a spacewalk. [The speaker talks about this at 12:50](https://youtu.be/jM8YvueNR7A?t=770) along with some trivia:

> "nobody had ever taken a Hasselblad into space since Apollo".

[Available images from the mission can be found here](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/SearchPhotos/mrf.pl?MRFList=STS061&scope=both). Comparing angles to the presentation clip, I speculate film magazine STS061-105 was used in the space Hasselblad (but I can't find anything confirming this).